# actionPerformed using two same buttons variable

Tags: java, user-interface, jbutton

```
JPanel btns = new JPanel();
btns.add(new JButton("btn1"));
btns.add(new JButton("btn2"));
btns.setLayout((new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING)));
southPanel.add(btns);
```

Hello, the above, I have provided the code. How would I make a actionPerformed method to certain button. For instance, when I click btn1, it will print out Button 1 is clicked. When I click btn2, it will print out Button 2 is clicked.

Thanks.

Comment: The first step would be to not add buttons to the panel in one line like that. You would make them both independently, add actionlisteners to both, then add them to the panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Create an instance of object to the Buttons..**

```
JButton button1 = new JButton("btn1");
JButton button1 = new JButton("btn1");
```

**then add them to the Panel**

```
btns.add(button1 );
btns.add(button2 );
```

**add the a action command to the Buttons:**

```
button1.setActionCommand("button1");
button2.setActionCommand("button2");\
```

**create a class that implements `ActionListener`**

```
private class Controller implements ActionListener
```

**In the actionPerformed get the actionCommand and checks it with the correnponding button:**

```
  @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
        {
            String actionCommand = evt.getActionCommand(); //get the actionCommand and pass it to String actionCommand

            if(actionCommand.equals("button1"))
                           //button 1 clicked
            else if(actionCommand.equals("button2"))
                          //button 1 clicked
}
```

Comment: @user3557085 did you implements actionlistener to you class?? can you post it..?

Answer (score 0):

You simply add two different ActionListener to the two buttons.

```
btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){.....});
btn2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){.....});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a handle to the buttons, and `.add(new JButton("btn1"))` doesn't allow you to access them easily.

Declare your buttons as variables, as in `JButton button = new JButton("btn1")`. Then, call their `.addActionListener(...)` method to define the actionListener to use.

Assuming that you want two *different* actionListeners, you can use the following.

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
        public void actionPerformed() {...} 
    } 
);
```

If you don't care about the buttons after they have an actionListener, you may use a temporary variable:

```
JButton temp = new JButton("btn1");
temp.addActionListener(...);
btns.add(temp); //adds btn1

temp = new JButton("btn2");
temp.addActionListener(...);
btns.add(temp); //adds btn2
```

Finally, if you want to use *one* actionListener to handle both buttons, use the `.setActionCommand()` method to give a unique command to each button. Then, in actionPerformed, use an if statement and check `e.getActionCommand.equals("myButton'sAction")`. 
For example:

```
JButton temp = new JButton("btn1");
temp.addActionListener(this);
temp.setActionCommand("Btn1");
btns.add(temp); //btn1

temp = new JButton("btn2");
temp.addActionListener(this);
temp.setActionCommand("Btn2");
btns.add(temp); //btn2

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String command = e.getActionCommand();
    if (e.getActionCommand.equals("Btn1"))
        System.out.println("Button 1 pressed");
    if (e.getActionCommand.equals("Btn2"))
        System.out.println("Button 2 pressed");
}
```